# Looking for online resources to understand game camera properties

Tags: camera

What are some good online resources to understand game camera properties, such as fov, aspect-ratio and more?

Answer (score 2):

it's not too complete and exaustive but maybe this could help: http://aoeu.snth.net/?p=43

Comment: That link has gone out of date (he moved his page).